# How to add a dynamic row in a table of SWT?

Tags: java, swt

[image]

in the above table how can I add dynamic row by clicking the `ADD..`-button, selecting the row and deleting the row by clicking `DEL..`-button

Comment: Are you just using `Table` and `TableItem` or are you using the JFace `TableViewer`?

Answer (score 0):

The following code (adapted from [Snippet 101](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet101.java)) does what you ask:

```
final Display display = new Display();
final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

final Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI);

final Button addButton = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
addButton.setText("Add item");
addButton.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
  @Override
  public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    final TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE, 0);
    item.setText("*** New Item " + table.indexOf(item) + " ***");
  }
});

final Button deleteButton = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
deleteButton.setText("Delete item");
deleteButton.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
  @Override
  public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    final TableItem[] selectedItems = table.getSelection();
    for (final TableItem item : selectedItems) {
      item.dispose();
    }
  }
});

final Rectangle clientArea = shell.getClientArea();
table.setBounds(clientArea.x, clientArea.y, 200, 200);
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  final TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
  item.setText("Item " + i);
}
shell.pack();
shell.open();
while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
  if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
    display.sleep();
  }
}
display.dispose();
```

The add button adds a new item at the top (index 0), the remove button removes all selected items (if any).